# Grub shows "lsb_release -i -s 2 ..." instead of "Ubuntu"

Tags: boot, grub2, lsb-release

After doing apt-get update my grub shows s "lsb_release -i -s 2  ..." instead of "Ubuntu". How to make it shows back "Ubuntu"? Of course I can edit it manually in /etc/boot/grub.cfg. But every doing update and upgrade with kernel it will shows again s "lsb_release -i -s 2  ..." as shown in the figure[image].

I guess I must edit something in /etc/default/grub.

Anyone experience with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some update and upgrade the problem disappear. Alternatively, you can re-configure all packages and prompt "new" instead of keep old configuration.

here the example,

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```